# Bash: append file on mulitple hosts

Tags: bash, ssh

What I want to do is run a pretty simple command:

```
cat content.txt >> target.file
```

but I want to do this on lots of hosts.

So I was approaching it like this:

- Have a list of hosts in a file
- Loop over the list and do `ssh $line 'cat content.txt >> target.file'`

but that didn't seem to be working, when testing with a simple echo "$line" I get back my lines.
When testing with a ssh $line 'ls' in the loop I get only one result.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat target_hosts.txt | while read line
do
  echo `ssh "$line" 'ls'`
done
```

Comment: Just `ssh "$line" ls` should work.

Comment: Of course there's nothing wrong with loops, but I would recommend a fancy tool: GNU parallel. See https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Running-the-same-commands-on-all-hosts

Comment: I don't think you can `cat` a local file into a remote machine. You probably have to copy it there and, once it is there, then `cat`.

Comment: @fedorqui Good catch, but I think he's not even there yet. According to the description, even `ls` doesn't work.

Comment: @fedorqui You can of course `cat` it like so: `ssh user@host 'cat >> target_file' < local_file`.

Comment: By the way, you can pipe the stdout of a local `cat` to the stdin of a remote `cat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to `cat` a file into another server, you can say what is suggested in [transfer file to remote host and append to file if existing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107910/40596):

```
somecommand | ssh somehost 'cat - >> file.log'
```

That is, use stdin as a feeder for `cat`. I just did a test and it works.

In your case, this should make it:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
   cat content.txt | ssh "$line" 'cat - >> target.file'
done < target_hosts.txt
```

Or, nicer, what [gniourf_gniourf suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365239/bash-append-file-on-mulitple-hosts/33365602?noredirect=1#comment54525868_33365602):

```
ssh "$line" 'cat - >> target.file' < content.txt
```

Or even better, just remove the `-` since it is the default for `cat` when not having any argument ([chepner's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365239/bash-append-file-on-mulitple-hosts/33365602?noredirect=1#comment54530159_33365602)):

```
ssh "$line" 'cat >> target.file' < content.txt
```

Comment: `ssh user@host 'cat >> target_file' < local_file` is nicer!

Comment: Mmmm to me it looks like an emoticon : )

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf added your recommendation for sake of completeness. Thanks : )

Comment: The hyphen is unnecessary; `cat` reads from standard input when it doesn't have any arguments.

Comment: @chepner good point, I wasn't aware of this. Updated, thanks!

Comment: That's actually what I suggested in the first place `:D`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf oops sorry, I just focused my attention in the indirection, not in the absence of the `-`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `ssh` command will *eat* your input from `target_hosts.txt`, you must redirect input of ssh to prevent it from eating your input

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
  ssh "$line" 'ls' < /dev/null
done < target_hosts.txt
```

More details:

```
while read line
do
  ssh "$line" 'ls' < /dev/null
done
```

is a sub-command whose input is file `target_hosts.txt`, and all command in this sub-command share the input. And there are 2 commands in the sub-command

- read
- ssh

Both `read` and `ssh` commands can read the input from `target_hosts.txt`. While `read` consume one line, then run `ssh`, by default `ssh` will consume all remain input, then there is nothing to read, your script ends

Comment: Instead of `< /dev/null` you could use a different file descriptor for the `read` command: `while read -r line <&3; do ssh "$line" 'ls'; done 3< target_hosts.txt`; or, using bashisms, `while read -ru3 line; do ssh "$line" 'ls' ; done 3< target_hosts.txt`; or even, letting the shell chose its file descriptor: `while read -ru"$fd" line; do ssh "$line" 'ls'; done {fd}< target_hosts.txt`.